# Найти точную высоту блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть div блок с высотой в которой есть дробная часть. Например 450.19px. Если использовать js свойство offsetHeight, то мы находим только целую часть высоты - 450. По видимому свойство возвращает округлённое значение.

Можно ли как то найти точное значение высоты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(elem)[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

Comment: Артём, работает. Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли как-то найти точное значение высоты?

Можно. В Вашем случае `450px`.

> Пиксель — это наименьшая единица растрового изображения.

Как Вы его собираетесь делить?

Работает округление: Если дробная часть меньше `0.5` - округляется до меньшего, если больше - округляется до большего. Т.е.,
когда Вы ставите высоту в `450.19px` реальная высота будет равна `450px`. Ставите `450.5px` - будет `451px`.

```
$(elem)[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

Покажет только значение, которое вы задали, но реальная высота будет целым числом.

Comment: Sv__t, Ваш вопрос как я собираюсь делить пиксель непонятен. Такой задачи не стояло и в заголовке вопроса она не фигурирует. По факту есть два блока - у оного высота 450, e второго - 450.19. Такие высоты блоков вижу в консоли хрома (или ff). Визуально разница между блоками по высоте заметна. Значит тот, в высоте у которого есть дробная часть .19px, не округляется в меньшую сторону. Если бы работало так как Вы описали, то данной бы темы не возникло.